# Bitrise "deploy to itunesconnect" step failing despite having profiles and certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, bitrise

## Context

I've been using Bitrise to deploy one single app on both Android and iOS.
It's always been working fine, knowing that the initial configuration had been done by a coworker who doesn't work with us anymore. I've mostly been maintaining the workflow and changing expired certificates/provisioning profiles so I don't know the initial configuration details.

## Problem

Recently we decided to split our app in two different apps from different repositories, so I needed to create a new Bitrise app.

Here’s what I’ve done:

- Created a new app on Bitrise based on our new repo
- Added the exact same steps that were in the other app
- Added all the same env variables
- Connected to Apple via Apple ID, tested the connection via the button on Bitrise (which was successful)
- Deleted all the old profiles on my Mac, archived the new app from XCode (v.13.4.1) and ran the Bitrise scripts that uploads the certificates and profiles (app-store and development) on the platform.

My certificates were successfully added to the project in the Code Signing tab.

However, when building, the step « deploy to itunesconnect » systematically fails with the following error:
`"Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle xxx is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal`

I find it weird because the « Certificate and profile installer » step is successful. I’ve tried several things suggested on forums (including stack overflow), for example adding the certificate on Bitrise directly downloaded from Apple connect (no Bitrise script), or creating a new certificate directly on Xcode, but nothing worked. People who had this error seemed to have issues on how their certificates themselves, but I'm wondering if I didn't do something wrong even before.

At this point I am a bit stuck. Anyone have an idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error in Bitrise. Actually, this is an Xcode upload error. You will get the same error in your Xcode with same certificate and provision which you uploaded in Bitrise.

To solve this, please export one development and one Production ipa. Also, check the certificate you are selecting using during the build upload.

Please check the below image and upload the same profile you select here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNLsM.png

Also you can use this tools by bit rise to export valid provision profiles and certificates.

https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/code-signing/ios-code-signing/collecting-and-exporting-code-signing-files-with-codesigndoc.html

This will work for manual code signing. Thanks